# event listeners are not working properly and else clause is not geting executed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a project where to move plane up down ,you will use arrow keys normally and to create the effect that it is moving back or forth, you move the track using arrow keys left and right so that plane appears to move relative to them. There are two problems I am facing in my Javascript code which I have mentioned in comments at line 35 and 58 of the script code

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Plane moving project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background">
        
        <svg class="button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 17h-5v-10h5v10zm2-10v10l9 5v-20l-9 5zm17 4h-5v2h5v-2zm-1.584-6.232l-4.332 2.5 1 1.732 4.332-2.5-1-1.732zm1 12.732l-4.332-2.5-1 1.732 4.332 2.5 1-1.732z"/></svg>
        <svg class="mute" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 17h-5v-10h5v10zm2-10v10l9 5v-20l-9 5zm15.324 4.993l1.646-1.659-1.324-1.324-1.651 1.67-1.665-1.648-1.316 1.318 1.67 1.657-1.65 1.669 1.318 1.317 1.658-1.672 1.666 1.653 1.324-1.325-1.676-1.656z"/></svg>
        <div class="plane">
        
        </div>
        
        
       
        
        <div class="track">
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    html,body{
        overflow: hidden;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    .background{
        background:url("background.jpg") center;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-size:cover;
        position: relative;
        
    }  
    .plane{
        height:20vh;
        width: 20vh;
        background:url("plane.png") center no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
       

    }
    .track{
     width:800vw;
     height:40%;
     background: url("track.png") no-repeat center;
      
     position: absolute;
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
    }
    svg{
        height: 10vh;
        width: 10vh;
        z-index: 3;
        top:0vh;
        left:0vh;
    }
    svg:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .mute svg{
        top:0vh;
        left:0vh;
        height: 10vh;
        width: 10vh;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .mute svg:hover{
        cursor:pointer;

    }
```

javascript:

```
let plane = document.querySelector(".plane");
let track = document.querySelector(".track");
plane.style.pos = "absolute";
plane.style.top = "30%";
track.style.pos = "relatiev";
track.style.top = "77%";
btn=document.querySelector('.button');
let mute=document.querySelector('.mute')
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.setAttribute('src','bgmusic.mp3');
mute.setAttribute('src','bgmusic.mp3');
btn.style.display="none";

let noaudio=true;
if(noaudio)
{
  mute.addEventListener("click",()=>{
   audio.loop=true;
      let promise=audio.play();
      if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(_ => {
          // Autoplay started!
        }).catch(error => {
          // Autoplay was prevented.
          // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
        });
        
        audio.muted=false;
        btn.style.display="block";
        mute.style.display="none";
      }
  });
  noaudio=false;
}
//if i replace this by else instead of if,it does not get executed
if(noaudio==false){
  btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    
   
    
      btn.style.display="none";
      mute.style.display="block";
      audio.pause();
      
    });
    noaudio=true;
    
}

let moveby = 1.8;

  
  let check=1;
  window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    
  switch (e.key) {
   
   //arrow left and arrow right events are not working
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      
      track.style.left = parseInt(track.style.left) +moveby + "%";
      break;
      
      case 'ArrowRight':
        
        track.style.left = parseInt(track.style.left) - moveby + "%";
        break;
        
        case 'ArrowUp': 
        
       plane.style.top= parseInt(plane.style.top) - moveby + "%";
        break;
        
        case 'ArrowDown':
          plane.style.top = parseInt(plane.style.top) + moveby + "%";
          break;
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you need the event listeners set up on the buttons *regardless* of whether or not the audio is currently playing.  *Within* the listeners you should check if the audio is playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should initialize your track style `track.style.left = "0%";`
2. You should use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.
3. You don't need the if else in your function, you can take out the eventlistener.
4. To answer your question: The else doesn't work because you enter the if block and update the value `noaudio=true;`. You only enter If or Else once and you are not going to reenter. If you separate two if, you can enter the second if again.

After all fix, it should work.

**Example below:** You can expand it full screen to see a better result.

```js
let plane = document.querySelector(".plane");
let track = document.querySelector(".track");
plane.style.pos = "absolute";
plane.style.top = "30%";
track.style.pos = "relative";
track.style.top = "77%";
track.style.left = "0%";
btn = document.querySelector(".button");
let mute = document.querySelector(".mute");
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.setAttribute("src", "https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3");
mute.setAttribute("src", "https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3");

let moveby = 1.8;

let check = 1;

mute.addEventListener("click", () => {
  audio.loop = true;
  let promise = audio.play();
  if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise
      .then(_ => {
        // Autoplay started!
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Autoplay was prevented.
        // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
      });

    audio.muted = false;
    btn.style.display = "block";
    mute.style.display = "none";
  }
});

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btn.style.display = "none";
  mute.style.display = "block";
  audio.pause();
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  switch (e.key) {
    //arrow left and arrow right events are not working
    case "ArrowLeft":
      track.style.left = parseFloat(track.style.left) + moveby + "%";
      break;

    case "ArrowRight":
      track.style.left = parseFloat(track.style.left) - moveby + "%";
      break;

    case "ArrowUp":
      plane.style.top = parseFloat(plane.style.top) - moveby + "%";
      break;

    case "ArrowDown":
      plane.style.top = parseFloat(plane.style.top) + moveby + "%";
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.background {
  background: url("https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2098/2260149771_00cb406fd6_o.jpg")
    center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.plane {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  background: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/73/01/74/240_F_173017473_xRG5TrDyf7elY5PPC7Xt89Ar3imtHwF4.jpg")
    center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.track {
  width: 800vw;
  height: 40%;
  background: url("https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/437/482/png-clipart-angle-divider-religion-line.png")
    no-repeat center;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
svg {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0vh;
  left: 0vh;
}
svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mute svg {
  top: 0vh;
  left: 0vh;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  z-index: 3;
}
.mute svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Plane moving project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="background">
      <svg
        class="button"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="24"
        height="24"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path
          d="M5 17h-5v-10h5v10zm2-10v10l9 5v-20l-9 5zm17 4h-5v2h5v-2zm-1.584-6.232l-4.332 2.5 1 1.732 4.332-2.5-1-1.732zm1 12.732l-4.332-2.5-1 1.732 4.332 2.5 1-1.732z"
        />
      </svg>
      <svg class="mute" height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
      </svg> 
        <path
          d="M5 17h-5v-10h5v10zm2-10v10l9 5v-20l-9 5zm15.324 4.993l1.646-1.659-1.324-1.324-1.651 1.67-1.665-1.648-1.316 1.318 1.67 1.657-1.65 1.669 1.318 1.317 1.658-1.672 1.666 1.653 1.324-1.325-1.676-1.656z"
        />
      </svg>
      <div class="plane"></div>

      <div class="button"></div>

      <div class="track"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i was unable to understand your fourth point.i have changed the value of noaudio for both cases .if noaudio was true it is changed to false else it was changed to true. why it is not working?

Comment: @coder_newbie, I updated point 4. Is this more clear?

Comment: when did i change the value of no audio to true in if statement?I have changed it to false only as you are saying.so shouldn't it work fine?

Comment: @coder_newbie, but the js only run one time for the if else. After you run one time, you did update the value. But you will not run the same if else again.

Comment: oh.now i understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to give initial position to track as well like

```
 track.style.left = "0%";
```

```js
let plane = document.querySelector(".plane");
let track = document.querySelector(".track");
plane.style.pos = "absolute";
plane.style.top = "30%";
track.style.pos = "absolute";
track.style.top = "77%";
track.style.left = "0%";
btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let mute = document.querySelector('.mute')
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.setAttribute('src', 'bgmusic.mp3');
mute.setAttribute('src', 'bgmusic.mp3');
btn.style.display = "none";

let noaudio = true;
if (noaudio) {
  mute.addEventListener("click", () => {
    audio.loop = true;
    let promise = audio.play();
    if (promise !== undefined) {
      promise.then(_ => {
        // Autoplay started!
      }).catch(error => {
        // Autoplay was prevented.
        // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.
      });

      audio.muted = false;
      btn.style.display = "block";
      mute.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
  noaudio = false;
}
//if i replace this by else instead of if,it does not get executed
if (noaudio == false) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {



    btn.style.display = "none";
    mute.style.display = "block";
    audio.pause();

  });
  noaudio = true;

}

let moveby = 1.8;


let check = 1;
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {

    //arrow left and arrow right events are not working
    case 'ArrowLeft':

      track.style.left = parseInt(track.style.left, 10) + moveby + "%";
      break;

    case 'ArrowRight':

      track.style.left = parseInt(track.style.left, 10) - moveby + "%";
      break;

    case 'ArrowUp':

      plane.style.top = parseInt(plane.style.top) - moveby + "%";
      break;

    case 'ArrowDown':
      plane.style.top = parseInt(plane.style.top) + moveby + "%";
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.background {
  background: url("background.jpg") center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.plane {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  background: url("https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.track {
  width: 800vw;
  height: 40%;
  background: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/photos/1893675319/display_1500/stock-photo-empty-asphalt-road-and-blue-sky-with-white-clouds-road-background-1893675319.jpg") no-repeat center;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  left: 0%;
}

svg {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 0vh;
  left: 0vh;
}

svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mute svg {
  top: 0vh;
  left: 0vh;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  z-index: 3;
}

.mute svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Plane moving project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="background">

    <svg class="button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 17h-5v-10h5v10zm2-10v10l9 5v-20l-9 5zm17 4h-5v2h5v-2zm-1.584-6.232l-4.332 2.5 1 1.732 4.332-2.5-1-1.732zm1 12.732l-4.332-2.5-1 1.732 4.332 2.5 1-1.732z"/></svg>
    <svg class="mute" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 17h-5v-10h5v10zm2-10v10l9 5v-20l-9 5zm15.324 4.993l1.646-1.659-1.324-1.324-1.651 1.67-1.665-1.648-1.316 1.318 1.67 1.657-1.65 1.669 1.318 1.317 1.658-1.672 1.666 1.653 1.324-1.325-1.676-1.656z"/></svg>
    <div class="plane">

    </div>




    <div class="track">
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```